# A kaldi function only has header file in C++

Tags: c++, kaldi

I tried to find the definition of a function `cblas_Xaxpy` in Kaldi, so I was directed by GOTO Definition to the final place `cblas-wrappers.h`, where I found

```
inline void cblas_Xaxpy(const int N, const float alpha, const float *X,
                        const int incX, float *Y, const int incY) {
  cblas_saxpy(N, alpha, X, incX, Y, incY);
}
```

Apparently the key is `cblas_saxpy`, first I tried to direct to the source file of this header file, but I did not find any. So I have tried search the whole directory and the parent directory concerning the project and I could not find any file containing the real definition of cblas_saxpy. But this is the original code and I ran it smoothly.

Then I am confused: if this is the correct version, then there should be some place to define the function `cblas_saxpy`'s implementation, but where is it ?

Comment: It is defined in the compiled library. You won't see the source code. It is already compiled into a binary object file and stored in the library archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cblas_saxpy()` is defined in the [LAPACK](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/) library. (As this is a C library, the source code does not need to be present to compile software against the library.) [The definition of `cblas_saxpy`](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/9fb29d8ea47d643ad44a67d3da5de36e280143f5/CBLAS/src/cblas_saxpy.c) in that library is a wrapper around [some extremely old Fortran code](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/9fb29d8ea47d643ad44a67d3da5de36e280143f5/BLAS/SRC/saxpy.f).